# delphi XE4 iOS app in debug launches, but get's stuck on the splash screen

Tags: ios, xcode, delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe4

I have an iOS app that runs fine on a Mac using the simulator. I have gone through the necessary steps to setup the provisioning and certificates, and have successfully debugged, and then ad-hoc deployed a very simple test app to an iPad.

However upon trying to deploy my app that makes use of a datasnap server, and actually does some serious work, I seems to be having problems. I can start the app, and step through the code up until I show a modal form in the onCreate method of the MainForm.

Then the form doesn’t show, and I can only see the splash screen still. Can I not show other forms modally in on create? I tried moving all the code to on show, as I saw a brief mention that another user ran into a similar problem and that this worked for him. however this did not work for me. This whole process works fine on the simulator.

Here is the beginnning of my onCreate method for the Main form

```
Ini := TUserIniFile.Create;

sMachineName := lIni.ReadString('name_preference', 'Machine Name or IP');

sPort := lIni.ReadString('port_preference', 'Port Number');


fmConfig := TfmConfig.Create(Self);

fmConfig.MachineName := sMachineName;

fmConfig.Port := sPort;

if fmConfig.ShowModal = mrOK then begin

  //setup DREST

  DSREST.Params.Values['Port'] := fmConfig.Port;

  DSREST.Params.Values['HostName'] := fmConfig.MachineName;
```

When the fmConfig.ShowModal is called, then the program stops (obviously, waiting for the return result from the modal form), but the form is never shown, and I can still only see the splash form at this point in debug mode. However this all works fine in the simulator.

Is there some restriction upon showing forms like this that is specific to deploying to the device and not the simulator?

EDIT:  I have removed the modal forms (I also had a login form in the on show method) and now I can at least get the application to run in debug mode on the device. Is this a genuine restriction on modal forms?

Comment: Did you deploy Midas library also? http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE4/en/IOS_Tutorial:_Connecting_to_an_Enterprise_Database_from_an_iOS_Client_Application#Deploy_the_MIDAS_Library_to_iOS_Simulator

Comment: I hadn't deployed the Midas Library, thanks for that, however I am still getting the same problem, the app appears stuck on the splash screen and never displays the modal config form.

Comment: And IP address is correct? Not localhost? Been there, done that. Also, modal dialogs are not recommended on either of the mobile platforms: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/What%27s_New_in_Delphi_and_C%2B%2BBuilder_XE5